# Como fazer um código HTML de busca igual ao do AIRBNB?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Gostaria de saber como fazer o mecanismo de busca que aparecesse o lugar com para fazer um Filtro de lugares e do lado tivesse check in, check out.. exatamente igual do airbnb, tentei desse jeito mas não funcionou:

JS:

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
      var nowTemp = new Date();
      var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
      var checkin = $('#checkin').datepicker({
        onRender: function(date) {
          return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
      }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
          var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
          newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
          checkout.setValue(newDate);
        }
        checkin.hide();
        $('#checkout')[0].focus();
      }).data('datepicker');
      var checkout = $('#checkout').datepicker({
        onRender: function(date) {
          return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
      }).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
        checkout.hide();
      }).data('datepicker');
    });
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.search {
 margin-top: -25%;
}
.search .form-section{
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 border: 2px solid #414141;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1">

  <title>Real Estate </title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/ie-support/html5.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ie-support/respond.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

 </head>


<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/sample1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/sample2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/sample3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="search">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
              <div class="form-section">
                <div class="row">
                    <form role="form">
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="sr-only" for="location">Location</label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Where ?">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="sr-only" for="checkin">Check in</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkin" placeholder="Check in">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="sr-only" for="checkout">Check out</label>
                          <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="checkout" placeholder="Check out">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="sr-only" for="guest">Guest</label>
                          <select id="guest" name="guest" class="form-control">
                              <option value="1">1 Guest</option>
                              <option value="2">2 Guests</option>
                              <option value="3">3 Guests</option>
                              <option value="4">4 Guests</option>
                              <option value="5">5 Guests</option>
                              <option value="6">6 Guests</option>
                              <option value="7">7 Guests</option>
                              <option value="8">8 Guests</option>
                              <option value="9">9 Guests</option>
                              <option value="10">10 Guests</option>
                              <option value="11">11 Guests</option>
                              <option value="12">12 Guests</option>
                              <option value="13">13 Guests</option>
                              <option value="14">14 Guests</option>
                              <option value="15">15 Guests</option>
                              <option value="16">16+ Guests</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary">Search</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Krosie, quanto ao filtro de lugares, você pode salvar todos dentro de um banco de dados e utilizar um plugin (ou criar) de autocomplete, exemplo http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/. Quanto ao checkin e o checkout, vai da mesma forma, só que a diferença é que terá de utilizar um Date picker.

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar isso!